# Command Problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok, so, i am making a map for minecraft, and i am having issues with a lot of commands. One of them is: `/execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=title] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ redstone_block * /tp @e[type=armor_stand,name=title] @e[type=armor_stand,name=spawn]`. Can someone tell me whats wrong with that?

Here is what it tells me: [image]

Comment: What's wrong with it? Does it not work? Does it give an error? We can't read your mind, so you have to tell us what's going on.

Comment: Ok, that was faster than i thought, but i'll add what it says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `@e[type=armor_stand,name=title]` add quotations between 'title'. Like this:

```
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,name="title"] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ redstone_block * /tp @e[type=armor_stand,name=title] @e[type=armor_stand,name=spawn]
```

**Edit:** This seems to not work, but in 17w17b i get this error instead:
[image]

**Edit 2:**
As i have researched your command, you are searching for a armor stand with a name with title, and also checks if it has a redstone block under it. Then it will tp the armor stand with "title" as title, to a armor stand with a "spawn" title

**Edit: 3**
Seems the first solution does not work, but i tested it some time and it worked.

Name Tag the Armor Stands with a Name Tag, and then it will work.

Watch a gif where i do it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bSKF.jpg

Comment: Let me try that. I don't think it will work but ok. _Edit_: Nope. It's now looking for ``"title"`` not ``title``.

Comment: Try the **Edit 3**.

Comment: Ok, now, if i name an armor stand with a name tag, will it still have the name when someone else loads up the files?

Comment: Yes, it should, as name it is an NBT. It is saved on the world files, not in the player files. Also, singleplayer worlds does not remove your items even with an another account.